# Render Widget as HTML in Code Behind

Tags: kentico

I have come across a situation where I'm needing to retrieve the rich text content of a page type column, and return that data/HTML as it would appear on a rendered page. A custom web part then serves aggregated data as nodes of XML or JSON.

For the most part this was easy enough in the code behind using DocumentQuery, however the problem is with widgets that have been inserted into the content.

My question is: **How do I "render" a widget purely in code?** Or even, what process is Kentico doing to render a widget that I might be able to reproduce?

I am somewhat familiar with the widget/web part/user control relationship, so I'm thinking a web part would need to be instantiated (somewhere, somehow) using the properties on the widget, and then accessing the RenderedHTML property of the web part.

Due to the format that widgets are stored in the data, I was hoping that they could just be Resolved with the MacroResolver, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

For reference, here is an example of how the out-of-the-box DateTime widget shows up:
{^widget|(jsuseservertime)False|(name)DateTime|(widget_displayname)Date+%26+time|(width)|(height)^}

Any input is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why you need to do this via a widget? If it's a content of some page type field (even rich text) you can simply get the treenode in the code and get the value of such a field.

Comment: I believe he is saying it's part of the DocumentContent column in the CMS_Document database, IE the text used in an "Editable Text" webpart.

Comment: Clarification: We are utilizing custom page type fields, with a data type of Long Text / Rich Text, that allow someone to enter rich content and custom widgets via the Form view. 

So for a simplistic example, if the rich text field has the content: 
"Hello, welcome to the site. The current time is <time-widget>"

The output when retrieving the corresponding database column would be:
"Hello, welcome to the site. The current time is 12:00"

The widgets in use are obviously more complex, and the pages don't necessarily have a template due to the "Container" type pages.

Comment: I meant the "Content only" page type flag, not the container flag :) The content editor may see only the "Content" tab and not the usual "Page", "Design" and "Form" tabs.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked this article http://devnet.kentico.com/articles/how-to-resolving-the-inline-controls? It is pretty old. But `CMS.ExtendedControls.ControlsHelper.ResolveDynamicControls` is available in newer Kentico versions. I think it might resolve you issue.